# BigQuery: grouping by similar strings for a large dataset

Tags: sql, string, google-bigquery

I have a table of invoice data with over 100k unique invoices and several thousand unique company names associated with them.

I'm trying to group these company names into more general groups to understand how many invoices they're responsible for, how often they receive them, etc.

Currently, I'm using the following code to identify unique company names:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT(company_name)
    FROM invoice_data
    ORDER BY company_name
```

The problem is that this only gives me exact matches, when its obvious that there are many string values in company_name that are similar. For example: McDonalds Paddington, McDonlads Oxford Square, McDonalds Peckham, etc.

How can I make by GROUP BY statement more general?

Sometimes the issue isn't as simple as the example listed above, occasionally there is simply an extra space or PTY/LTD which throws off a GROUP BY match.

**EDIT**

To give an example of what I'm looking for, I'd be looking to turn the following:

```
company_name
----------------------            
Jim's Pizza Paddington|
Jim's Pizza Oxford    |
McDonald's Peckham    |
McDonald's Victoria   |
-----------------------
```

And be able to group by their company name rather than exclusively with an exact string match.

Comment: This is not something that databases are really suitable for.

Comment: provide example of your data - just sample and expected result

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant added.

Comment: And what logic you have in mind to identify company name from above strings? Btw - what those strings are? Are there any other columns in that table which can anyhow be used as a hints?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Conceptually, I imagine that a more general GROUP BY query with a LIKE condition would achieve what I'm looking to do.


There is also a column with a unique identification number given for each company name, however, these are unique to franchises of companies which are in effect the same. This would solve the typo problem but not the franchise issue.

Comment: My question about the logic stays the same - forget for a second about SQL - just what logic you would have in mind to extract company name from strings?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I imagine that if there is a certain number (or proportion) of identical characters between row then I would be able to identify them as being the same company. For example, if 80% of characters between two company_name rows are identical and in the same order then I would say they're in the same company.

Comment: great point! just wanted to hear this from you - so see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60103870/5221944  - not necessarily will work for your case as is - but you have a chance here.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant thanks for your help! I'll give it a crack

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [Soundex function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#soundex)?

```
SELECT 
  SOUNDEX(name) AS code,
  MAX( name) AS sample_name,
  count(name) as records
FROM ((
    SELECT
      "Jim's Pizza Paddington" AS name)
  UNION ALL (
    SELECT
      "Jim's Pizza Oxford" AS name)
  UNION ALL (
    SELECT
      "McDonald's Peckham" AS name)
  UNION ALL (
    SELECT
      "McDonald's Victoria" AS name))
GROUP BY
  1
ORDER BY
```

You can then use the soundex to create groupings, with a split or other type of function to pull the part of the string which matches the name group or use a windows function to pull back one occurrence to get the name string.  Not perfect but means you do not need to pull into other tools with advanced language recognition.

[image: Code example image]